# InnoDB - bidirectional many-to-many foreign key check

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm trying to establish a many-to-many relationship within a table: a `keyword` can related to another `keyword`, and when that relation is added, the other direction must also be established.

Running on `10.5.9-MariaDB`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `related_keywords` (
  `relation_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Laravel/Eloquent pk crutch',
  `keyword_1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `keyword_2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`relation_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rel_kw_left_to_right` (`keyword_1`,`keyword_2`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rel_kw_right_to_left` (`keyword_2`,`keyword_1`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rel_kw_1_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`keyword_1`) REFERENCES `keywords` (`keyword_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rel_kw_2_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`keyword_2`) REFERENCES `keywords` (`keyword_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_related_kw_lr` FOREIGN KEY (`keyword_1`, `keyword_2`) REFERENCES `related_keywords` (`keyword_2`, `keyword_1`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ck_rel_kw_differ` CHECK (`keyword_1` <> `keyword_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

In order to add one, the other must also be added. Likewise, removing one row must remove the other. However, I can't add the first one without adding the second one due to the foreign key check enforcing this:

```sql
INSERT INTO related_keywords (keyword_1, keyword_2) VALUES
    (119250770368532480, 119251038153871360),
    (119251038153871360, 119250770368532480);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`keyword_db`.`related_keywords`, CONSTRAINT `fk_related_keyword_lr` FOREIGN KEY (`keyword_1`, `keyword_2`) REFERENCES `related_keywords` (`keyword_2`, `keyword_1`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE )
```

Now, I tried running it in a transaction, but it still seems to check the foreign keys (which I found odd). The only way that I can actually get it to add is to disable foreign key checks during the INSERT, which I *really* don't like.

The ideal solution here would be to make it so that, on the application level, all I had to do was:

```sql
INSERT INTO related_keywords (keyword_1, keyword_2) VALUES (119250770368532480, 119251038153871360);
```

and the matching row would be automatically added as well, with no problem from the `fk_related_kw_lr` foreign key check.

I've searched through docs for MariaDB and InnoDB in general and even with MariaDB 10.x's newer features I can't seem to work out a way to

- Temporarily disable a single (out of several) constraint
- Defer constraint checks until the end of the transaction
- ...and also insert the matching opposite-direction row when the first one is inserted

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- The PK is useless
- Only one `UNIQUE` is needed
- 3 uniques slows down inserts.
- Optimal many-to-many:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- I doubt if you need "cascade".
- Drop the FKs, they can be more trouble than they are worth.
- Instead of adding 2 rows, consider adding one row with the following.  (This may help or may complicate things, depending of what uses you have for this table.)

  ```
    LEAST(1234, 2345),
    GREATEST(1234, 2345)
  ```

Comment: 1. PK (marked a a crutch) is needed due to lack of composite primary key support in the Eloquent framework. Don't have choice in that matter.
2. Good catch on redundant unique keys!
3. Your linked many-to-many implements two different tables but mine uses the same table
4. Need the foreign keys/CASCADES because keywords can be deleted
5. Self-referential foreign key is used to mandate the two bidirectional rows must exist. Possible to replace this with a trigger, maybe?

Comment: @AustinBurk - Condolences on using a lame framework.  Can you sneak behind its back and change the schema after it creates it?  Trigger...  Maybe.  Is performance an issue?